# Setting up an automated email forwarding system for a large set of email accounts

Tags: email, postfix

Let's say I want people to send emails to my server and I want to forward them all to different email addresses. For example, I have a following mapping:

```
john@myserver.net => john.doe@someothermail.com
mary@myserver.net => poppins@yetanothermail.com
vlad@myserver.net => vlad@anotheranothermail.com
...
tom@myserver.net => tom@anothermail.com
```

This list may grow to a huge number and I want to be able to forward them all easily. I also want to let users easily configure so that they can set the mapping for themselves (Just like how you can easily set up forwarding on gmail, etc.)

I currently have postfix on my server but it seems like with postfix I have to edit the config file and reload all the time and it doesn't sound scalable when I'm thinking of a huge list.

What is the best way to achieve this? I don't necessarily have to go with postfix and can use entirely different system that fits this purpose if needed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Postfix supports a lot of [lookup tables](http://www.postfix.org/DATABASE_README.html) and you can use database lookup tables (`mysql,pgsql or sqlite`)to store such large lists and you need not reload postfix when using them. Say you have a table `forwards` in your postgres database with columns `emailaddress` and `forwards`.

```
emailaddress         forwards
john@myserver.net    john.doe@someothermail.com
mary@myserver.net    poppins@yetanothermail.com
vlad@myserver.net    vlad@anotheranothermail.com
```

and you can configure your postfix to use it.

```
#/etc/postfix/main.cf
#... other main.cf contents omitted
virtual_alias_domains = myserver.net
virtual_alias_maps = pgsql:/etc/postfix/pgsql_forwards.cf
#...
```

and the content of `/etc/postfix/pgsql_forwards.cf` should be something like

```
#/etc/postfix/pgsql_forwards.cf
dbname = emaildb
hosts = db.example.net
user = emailuser
password = somerandompass
query = SELECT forwards FROM forwards where emailaddress='%s';
```

- But first ensure what all lookup tables are compiled with your postfix by running `postconf -m`. I have seen many using `mysql`.
- And to enable your users to setup forwards themselves, you will have to give them some webapp that will update the database table used by postfix.

Hope that helps.

Comment: Thank you! Turns out my default config didn't have pgsql support so I had to install it using `apt-get install postfix-pgsql` and now it's all working fine!